# python 3 boolean logic shortcut

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have code that looks something like this:

```
x = someIntValue
if y is None:
    y = x

elif x < y:
    y = x
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this?
eg, something like: `y = x if x < y or not y`?

the issue is that `y` can be `None` and or a number

Comment: Do you mean: `y = x if (y is None or x < y) else y`?

Comment: Also you can use: y = x if (not y or x < y) else y
If y = 0 is needed to replace with x.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I'm not sure if saying `y is None` is the same as saying `not y`

Comment: @obsidian93 `y is None` means `y is None`. `not y` is completely different. For example `y = ""; not y -> True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the end results for both the condition is same, you can combine them into one if.

```
if y is None or x < y :
    y = x
```

As explained by @Giacomo in comments, a one liner version for this can be (since y is already defined)

```
y = x if ( y is None or x < y ) else y
```

Comment: does this work because it's lazily evaluating that `y is None` before it gets to `x < y`?

Comment: @obsidian93 Yes, [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not). It throws error when we evaluate `x<y or y is None` and `y=None`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write this exactly using a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), as `y` do not get assigned at all in the case that both boolean expressions are `False` (well, if you are willing to reassign `y` to itself, you can). You can or course get by without the `elif`:

```
x = someIntValue
if y is None or x < y:
    y = x
```

(I presume that `y` also has a value prior to this).

Your `x < y or not y` is bad for two reasons. First, it evaluates `x < y` before `not y`, which fails if `y` is `None`. Second, `not y` is not logically equivalent to `y is None`. For example, for `y = 0`, `not y` results in `True` while `y is None` results in `False`.